# Parallel Programing with Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

Okay, I am bit confuse on what and how should I do. I know the theory of Parallel Programming and Threading, but here is my case:

We have number of log files in given folder. We read these log files in database. Usually reading these files take couple of hours to read, as we do it in serial method, i.e. we iterate through each file, then open a SQL transaction for each file and insert the log in database, then read another and do the same.

Now, I am thinking of using Parallel programming so I can consume all core of CPU, however I am still not clear if I use Thread for each file, will that make any difference to system? I mean if I create say 30 threads then will they run on single core or they run on Parallel ? How can I use both of them? if they are not already doing that?

EDIT: I am using Single Server, with 10K HDD Speed, and 4 Core CPU, with 4 GB RAM, no network operation, SQL Server is on same machine with Windows 2008 as OS. [can change OS if that help too :)].

**EDIT 2**: I run some test to be sure based on your feedbacks, here is what I found on my i3 Quad Core CPU with 4 GB RAM

1. CPU remains at 24-50% CPU1, CPU2 remain under 50% usage, CPU3 remain at 75% usage and CPU4 remains around 0%. Yes I have Visual studio, eamil client and lot of other application open, but this tell me that application is not using all core, as CPU4 remain 0%;
2. RAM remain constantly at 74% [it was around 50% before test], that is how we design the read. So, nothing to worry
3. HDD remain READ/Write or usage value remain less than 25% and even it spike to 25% in sine wave, as our SQL transaction first stored in memory and then it write to disk when memory is getting threshold, so again,

So all resources are under utilized here, and hence I think I can distribute work to make it efficient. Your thoughts again. Thanks.

Comment: Before changing hardware try to enhance the software, should be less troubles ;)

Comment: yeah, I am rewriting the software to increase speed :) and hence this question.

Comment: No offense, but from your question, it seems you don't know the theory of parallel programming and threads.

Comment: well, svick maybe you are right and my knowledge is limited, but can you please share some thought so I can improve my understanding as well?

Comment: @SumitGupta It's beyond the scope of a single SO question to try to teach someone parallel programming from the ground up.  It's simply too broad of a topic.

Comment: @Servy, I am reading about parallel programming and threading, but I Am not able to pick which one is good for my design, and believe me there is hardly any book to define these things, so I look for experience developer's help to suggest a path from their experience. Maybe i am thinking wrong that my question can be answered, but already I got lot of light on my question and I am about to reach my goal :) thanks to your eye openers...

Comment: @SumitGupta There are *lots* of books on this subject.  If you think that information on this topic isn't widely available then you either haven't looked, or were simply mistaken.  Additionally, asking a question like "should I use parallelization or threading" doesn't really make sense.  It's not a question you should ever need to ask.  The fact that you're asking it at all means you need to take a step back, start from the beginning, and learn the proper concepts involved fully so that you can ask meaningful questions that might help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand your code and *why* is it slow. If you're thinking something like “my code is slow and uses one CPU, so I'll just make it use all 4 CPUs and it will be 4 times faster”, then you're most likely wrong.

Using multiple threads makes sense if:

1. Your code (or at least a part of it) is CPU bound. That is, it's not slowed down by your disk, your network connection or your database server, it's slowed down by your CPU.
2. Or your code has multiple parts, each using a different resource. E.g. one part reads from a disk, another part converts the data, which requires lots of CPU and last part writes the data to a remote database. (Parallelizing this doesn't actually require multiple threads, but it's usually the simplest way to do it.)

From your description, it sounds like you could be in situation #2. A good solution for that is the producer consumer pattern: Stage 1 thread reads the data from the disk and puts it into a queue. Stage 2 thread takes the data from the queue, processes them and puts them into another queue. Stage 3 thread takes the processed data from the second queue and saves them to the database.

In .Net 4.0, you would use `BlockingCollection<T>` for the queue between the threads. And when I say “thread”, I pretty much mean `Task`. In .Net 4.5, you could use blocks from TPL Dataflow instead of the threads.

If you do it this way then you can get up to three times faster execution (if each stage takes the same time). If Stage 2 is the slowest part, then you can get another speedup by using more than one thread for that stage (since it's CPU bound). The same could also apply to Stage 3, depending on your network connection and your database.

Comment: @SumitGupta I think getting general statistics is not enough. You should measure your application to know which part of the application slows you down.

Comment: well, I think I got some idea to move on, nothing is really blocking as application is under utilizing the resources on all end, the only blocking is software design, and that is why the question. I am moving with your suggested Task Library, and see if it really speed things up. Thanks for your guide again.

Answer (score 2):

There is no definite answer to this question and you'll have to test because as mentionned in my comments:

- if the bottleneck is the disk I/O then you won't gain a lot by adding more threads and you might even worsen performance because more threads will be fighting to get access to the disk
- if you think disk I/O is OK but CPU loads is the issue then you can add some threads, but no more than the number of cores because here again things will worsen due to context switching
- if you can do more disk and network I/Os and CPU load is not high (very likely) then you can oversubscribe with (far) more threads than cores: typically if your threads are spending much of their time waiting for the database

So you should profile first, and then (or directly if you're in a hurry) test different configurations, but chances are you'll be in the third case. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should check what is taking the time. If the CPU actually is the bottleneck, parallel processing will help. Maybe it's the network and a faster network connection will help. Maybe buying a faster disc will help.

Find the problem before thinking about a solution.

Comment: I am reading from local machine on 10K speed disk, client is ready to get SSD as well, but problem is only single core is used in serial process, and we have quad core CPU in general, so I think with parallel we can get speed.

Comment: Did you measure that the CPU is actually at it's limit? Did you measure the bandwith used when transferring data to the database?

Comment: With more cores things could be worst if the bottleneck are I/Os.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not using all CPU, your action are mainly I/O (reading file , sending data to DB).

Using Thread/Parallel will make your code run faster since you are processing many files at the same time.

To answer your question , the framework/OS will optimize running your code over the different cores.

Comment: Not sure it will run faster if the single thread is consuming all the I/O bandwidth, disk bus bandwidth and network bandwidth for access to the DB. OK not so likely :)

Comment: not likely. Also - there are several I/O like dist & network. 1 thread can take full bandwidth of 1 (like disk) but not use the network at the same time. multi thread can use all the I/O (like 1 thread taking the disk and 1 the network)

Comment: One thread can consume the full bandwidth of both if it **streams** the input from the disk to the DB. :)

Answer (score 1):

It varies from machine to machine but speaking generally if you have a dual core processor and you have 2 threads the Operating System will pass one thread to one core and the other thread to the other. It doesn't matter how many cores you use what matters is whether your equation is the fastest. If you want to make use of Parallel programming you need a way of sharing the workload in a way that logically makes sense. Also you need to consider where your bottleneck is actually occurring. Depending on the size of the file it may be simply the max speed of your read/write of the storage medium that is taking so long.As a test I suggest you log where the most time in your code is being consumed.

A simple way to test whether a non-serial approach will help you is to sort your files in some order divide the workload between 2 threads doing the same job simultaneously and see if it makes a difference. If a second thread doesn't help you then I guarantee 30 threads will only make it take longer due to the OS having to switch threads back and fourth.

Comment: My question is about if I should use Parallel programming or threading or both. Like If I use parallel for reading files, which is logically not related, each log has seperate entry of seperate datetime stamp, doesn't matter which file get read first or when, Then it put reading two to processor, but still threading will help further more ? seems it is more of test case, but general idea is what I am looking. thanks for your reply though.

Comment: If there is a lot of I/O you can consider far more threads than there are cores. As an example when you download files from network having dozens of threads is a good idea because what takes time is waiting for the data to come.

Comment: Sumit, if you are not maxing out your read/write and spending most of your time processing the information in some way rather than reading and writing it then multiple threads should help in theory. I this because if you are reading the max speed capable by your medium then multi-threading can't help that. As Pragmateek points out however many operations such as downloading files from multiple places certainly would be a good idea to use multiple threads so if one position lags it won't freeze up or slow down the entire operation unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest constructs in .Net 4 for parallel programming, threads are generally managed for you... take a read of [getting started with parallel programming](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx)
(pretty much the same as what has happened more recently with async versions of functions to use if you want it async)

e.g.

```
for (int i = 2; i < 20; i++)
{
    var result = SumRootN(i);
    Console.WriteLine("root {0} : {1} ", i, result);
}
```

becomes

```
Parallel.For(2, 20, (i) =>
{
    var result = SumRootN(i);
    Console.WriteLine("root {0} : {1} ", i, result);
});
```

**EDIT**: That said, it would be productive / faster to perhaps also put intensive tasks into seperate threads... but to manually make your application 'Multi-Core' and have things like certain threads running on particular cores, that isn't currently possible, that's all managed under the hood...

have a look at [plinq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx) for example
and [.Net Parallel Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_FX_Library)
and look into

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = 4
```

**Edit2**:
Parallel processing can be done inside a single core with multiple threads.

Multi-Core processing means distributing those threads to make use of the multiple cores in a CPU.

Comment: Well, I know the syntax thanks for that. as I mention my question is on conceptual design of application :).

Comment: My initial comment was in my opinion on the conceptual design, i.e. .Net includes some parallel extensions and therein that threads are managed for you... P.S. Read the edits

Comment: Multi-Core is not always Parallelisation

Comment: okay, thanks for your guide. I think the best thing is to experiment only :).